# iOS - TapRecogniser in custom TableViewCell not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am using Xcode 7 Beta, Swift 2
I have a table view with a custom tableViewCell. In the custom cell there is a UIImageView and Label. I have defined a testCell class for this tableViewCell as well. On the image (within the table) I have added UITapRecogniser. I have also enabled User Interaction

Issue: Currently I have 3 rows in the table. When I click on images on first 2 rows. Nothing happens. When I click on the image in the last row - the action prints "DEF" on the console. This has got nothing to with number of rows - problem persists even after changing to 4, 5 or anything else. Basically only the image in the last row gets tapped. Not sure why?? Below is the code:

```
//Defining custom class for the TableViewCell
class testCell : UITableViewCell{
@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var testImage: UIImageView!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! testCell
    cell.testLabel?.text = "ABC"
    cell.testImage?.image = UIImage(named: "Santa")
    return cell

}

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

//TapGestureRecogniser Function
@IBAction func imageTap(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("DEF")
}
```

Comment: move the add gesture recognizer call from testCell to cellforrowatindexpath.
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! testCell
    cell.testLabel?.text = "ABC"
    cell.testImage?.image = UIImage(named: "Santa")
    let cellTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("handleTap:"))
    cellTapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    cell.testImage?.addGestureRecognizer(cellTapRecognizer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the add gesture recognizer call from testCell to cellforrowatindexpath.

```
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! testCell
    cell.testLabel?.text = "ABC"
    cell.testImage?.image = UIImage(named: "Santa")
    let cellTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("imageTap:"))
    cellTapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    cell.testImage?.addGestureRecognizer(cellTapRecognizer)
```